# Select Distinct from new tol old in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table named:
**thread_comment**

Now the table is getting filled as followed:

```
thread_comment_id   thread_id   user_id   thread_comment       thread_comment_time
       1               2           1     This is a comment     2016-09-14 15:30:28
       2               4           1     This is a comment     2016-09-14 15:32:28
       3               2           1     This is a comment     2016-09-14 15:33:28
       4               5           1     This is a comment     2016-09-14 15:34:28
       5               7           1     This is a comment     2016-09-14 15:35:28
       6               2           1     This is a comment     2016-09-14 15:37:28
       7               2           1     This is a comment     2016-09-14 15:40:28
```

I want to show the newest threads to my page. for example:

as number one i want thread_comment_id **7**
as number two i want thread_comment_id **5**

I skipped **6** because i don't want any duplicates in the list.

In order to do so i did the folowing:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT thread_id FROM thread_comment ORDER BY thread_comment_time DESC"
```

This is kind of working (Not showing any duplicates). However the order does not make any sense...

For example:

It goes like 5 - 6 -4 - 7 etc...

Comment: In your example you are ordering by a different column name than in your example. Is this just a mistype?

Comment: Made an edit @JacobMorris it was a mistype :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column used in the `ORDER BY` isn't specified in the `DISTINCT`. You need to use an **aggregate function** and `GROUP BY` to make the `DISTINCT` work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT thread_id, max(thread_comment_id) FROM thread_comment GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY max(thread_comment_id) DESC, thread_id
```

EDIT: added aggregate func max()
Also thread_id is not mandatory in the `ORDER BY`

Comment: This is still giving me a random order :/

Comment: true, I forgot the aggregate max()

Comment: It is showing me the oldest first, then the newest. Switching from DESC to ASC dit not work

Comment: Do you edit the thread_comment_time field at some point ? if not you can use thread_comment_id instead : max(thread_comment_id). I'm not sure of what max() does with dates. Gonna take a look.

Comment: I understand the code, however it is still giving me a strange (not right) order :/

Comment: what kind of strange order ? shuffled ?

Comment: I wish i could show, but i'm on laptop with internet en pc with internet.. It is shuffled yes. Or at least not in good order! I will try to edit my question to what i have, and what i get. Just need a few minutes

Comment: i made a mistake in my request. Change the end to : `ORDER BY max(thread_comment_id) DESC, thread_id` (notice thread_id  position). Also thread_id is not mandatory in the ORDER BY

Comment: Thank You very much @Simon PA It's working as it should now :)

Comment: finally ! Sorry for the blind mistake ;-)

Comment: Haha no worries, more then happy that is is working :)

Answer (score 0):

It I understand correctly, you want one row per thread.  Here is a way to do this:

```
select tc.*
from thread_comment tc
where tc.thread_date = (select max(tc2.thread_date)
                        from thread_comment tc2
                        where tc2.thread_id = tc.thread_id
                       );
```

Comment: I want all the active threads to be shown. (Active is when a user added a comment on the thread). But i don't want to show double threads.